# sp_prepare fails with SELECT * INTO #tmpTable but not sp_prepexec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc, prepared-statement, jtds

I ran into a weird problem when switching to the jTDS driver (1.3) instead of using Microsoft JDBC driver (4.0.2206).

Here is the DDL for the example code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] varchar(10) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id])
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Test([Value]) VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO Test([Value]) VALUES('2')
```

After running the code with the profiler open I saw that MS driver is doing (which work):

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=null
exec sp_prepexec @p1 OUTPUT, NULL, N'SELECT *
INTO #tmpTable
FROM Test
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
DROP TABLE #tmpTable'
```

And jTDS issues (which gives "Invalid object name '#tmpTable'" (and no exception is thrown in java)):

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=null
exec sp_prepare @p1 OUTPUT, NULL, N'SELECT *
INTO #tmpTable
FROM Test
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
DROP TABLE #tmpTable'
exec sp_execute @p1
```

Why does sp_prepare and sp_execute differs from sp_prepexec when according to documentation sp_prepexec is the former procedures combined?

Why cannot the #tmpTable be found in the second query when doing sp_prepare?